# Manjaro i3 fresh install; dmenu not working

Tags: manjaro, i3, dmenu

**dmenu not working in  a fresh i3 setup**

This is the second time this is happening for me. (I reinstalled it)

The error I get is,

```
warning: no locale support
warning: no locale modifiers support
```

My `locale -a` output is,

```
C
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
POSIX
```

I tried the [method suggested in Manjaro Wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=DMenu).

The contents of `/etc/bin/dmenu_run` is,

```
#!/bin/sh
LANG="en_IN"
dmenu_path | dmenu "$@" | ${SHELL:-"/bin/sh"} &
```

I tried the values `en_IN`, `en_IN.UTF-8` and also `en_IN.utf8` for `LANG` in the `dmenu_run` file. Nothing worked.

---

I tried to follow [this Arch community conversation](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219327) to some extent. (I guess the problem is with Xorg) But I couldn't proceed because of the following reason.

After running the `localeconfig.c` program said in the `#9` conversation there, I can see that mine too is similar to that case. I got output,

```
locale yup
Xorg nay
```

But I couldn't follow as I got the following output for the command

```
pacman -Qo /usr/share/X11/locale/locale.dir
/usr/share/X11/locale/locale.dir is owned by libx11 1.6.9-6
```

---

I don't know what to do, now. Manjaro has always been a pleasure to install and try out. I'm quite a distro hopper. But I'm finally trying to settle down.

TIA for your time and effort! 
:heart:

Comment: A user from reddit pointed me to use Rofi instead

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what exactly is the issue, but changing the locale to US, solved it.

[Instructions to change the locale:](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Locale)

1. Edit the file `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` (if it isn't already).
2. Run `sudo locale-gen` to generate the updated locale.
3. Run `sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to set that particular locale.
4. Reboot.

You can see the updated values by running `locale` command.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.